Disabling button if the button name is = to datagridview data. (Stock Mapping)
I have problem in my code where it only triggers the else condition, if I remove the else condition I get the proper output. I need the else condition because when I switch tabs it should reset if the other tab doesn't contain any data.
Sub filterdb()
    Dim dgvposition As New DataGridView 

    Dim query As String = "SELECT POSITION FROM log_inventory WHERE BUILDING=@building AND STORAGE=@storage AND RACK=@rack" 

    con.open 

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@building", lbl_building.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@storage", lbl_storage.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rack", lbl_rack.Text)

    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

    Dim table As New DataTable
    adapter.Fill(table)
    
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
    
    con.close
End Sub

Sub check_available()
    Try
        Dim btnname As String
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            For Each btn In TabPage4.Controls
                If TypeOf btn Is Button Then
                    btnname = btn.text
                    If row.Cells(0).Value = btn.Text Then
                        btn.BackColor = Color.Red
                        btn.Enabled = False
                    Else
                        btn.BackColor = Color.Green
                        btn.Enabled = True
                    End If

                End If
            Next
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub


If row.Cells(0).Value = btn.Text Then: There must be a better way to check string equality than If object = string Then. Convert to string, do trimming if needed, take the case into account. That's a start

You don't have to call con.Open when loading data via SqlDataAdapter.Fill method. So, con.Close is also no longer needed.

In addition to not calling con.Open(), don't try to keep the same con variable around at all. This interferes with connection pooling in ADO.NET and makes things slower, with MORE memory use rather than less, and forces things to run in serial/sequence that might otherwise run at the same time. Instead, connection objects should be short-lived, and you really should be making a brand new connection object instance for most queries. Really. Ideally within a Using block.

The below code includes a number of improvements, even if it doesn't end up helping with the question. That is, you should use this even if it doesn't fix the question.
But I think it will help with the question by using a different strategy for matching the buttons, and moving that part to a separate pass through the data.
Sub filterdb()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT POSITION FROM log_inventory WHERE BUILDING=@building AND STORAGE=@storage AND RACK=@rack" 
    Dim table As New DataTable

    ' connections should be **short-lived**!
    Using con As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con), _
          adapter As New SqlAdapter(cmd)

        ' Be wary of AddWithValue()!
        ' Better to set explicit DB types than let ADO.NET try to infer them.
        ' I had to guess here. You should use the actual types/lengths from the DB
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@building", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value =  lbl_building.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@storage", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 60).Value = lbl_storage.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@rack", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = lbl_rack.Text
   
        adapter.Fill(table) ' No open/close needed for .Fill()
    End Using
    
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
End Sub

 ' Nothing in here was gonna throw, so I removed try/catch
Sub check_available()
    ' suspend/resume to stop flickering as the form redraws
    SuspendLayout()

    ' Set ALL buttons to the default
    ' Layout is suspended, so user can't see this yet
    For Each btn In TabPage4.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
        btn.BackColor = Color.Green
        btn.Enabled = True
    Next

    ' Find just the matching buttons
    Dim ButtonKeys = DataGridView1.Rows.Select(Function(r) r.Cells(0).Value.ToString())
    Dim buttons = TabPage4.Controls.OfType(Of Button)().
         InsertsectBy(ButtonKeys, Function(b) b.Text )

    ' Put back only the matching buttons.
    ' Yes, this is an extra pass through the set... but it 
    ' lets the CPU get better branch prediction so it's usually still faster.
    For Each btn In buttons
        btn.BackColor = Color.Red
        btn.Enabled = False
    Next

    ResumeLayout()
End Sub

If it still doesn't work, you should make sure the strings in the buttons really do match the strings from the grid, and adjusting as needed.
For example, the selector from the grid could look like this if needed:
Dim ButtonKeys = DataGridView1.Rows.Select(Function(r) r.Cells(0).Value.ToString().Trim().ToLower())

And instead of just b.Text the selector for the button could be b.Text.Trim().ToLower()

But I also wonder if the problem is one of timing and forms memory optimization. That is, at the point where this runs, the DataGridView might not have any rows. Knowing they are not on the screen, the form may have thrown them out to save memory. In that case, you may need to compare with the DB directly, or you may want to change the scope for the DataTable you set as the source so it remains as a member of the class, and compare to that.

If it were me, I'd also convert the filterdb() method to a function that returns the datatable as a value and accepts the textbox contents as arguments. Then the calling code would be responsible for assigning the result to the grid's DataSource. (Also: give it a more-specific name):
Function GetInventoryPositions(building As String, storage As String, rack As String) As DataTable
    Dim query As String = "SELECT POSITION FROM log_inventory WHERE BUILDING=@building AND STORAGE=@storage AND RACK=@rack" 
    Dim result As New DataTable

    ' connections should be **short-lived**!
    Using con As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con), _
          adapter As New SqlAdapter(cmd)

        ' Be wary of AddWithValue()!
        ' Better to set explicit DB types than let ADO.NET try to infer them.
        ' I had to guess here. You should use the actual types/lengths from the DB
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@building", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value =  building
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@storage", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 60).Value = storage
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@rack", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = rack
   
        adapter.Fill(table) ' No open/close needed for .Fill()
    End Using
    
    Return table
End Function

And then the calling code would now look like this:
DataGridView1.DataSource = GetInventoryPositions(lbl_building.Text, lbl_storage.Text, lbl_rack.Text)


yes if I code: else btn.text <> row.cells(0).value it also reads the blank cells. if I remove the else condition the code works and matches the texts but if I want to switch tabs I need to reset the condition. I also think if I ditch the else condition and put a reset code on tab control when I switch tabs.
